# wireshark protocol filter not working

Tags: error-handling, protocols, wireshark, mdns

i have this Wireshark snapshot and im trying to filter for the *mdns* protocol by just typing: mdns
but it's not working. however filtering for *http* is working fine. 
whats am i doing wrong?
Thanks
![wireshark error] https://www.dropbox.com/s/4zt6nf3f66te5ka/wireshar_pic.PNG?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the Protocol column shows "MDNS", the actual Protocol "field" for display filters to match is "`dns`", as far as Wireshark is concerned. So using a display filter of "`dns`" will match DNS packets, including MDNS. To then narrow it down to *only* MDNS, add the UDP port number of 5353, so the final display filter would be:

```
dns and udp.port == 5353
```

...or just "`udp.port == 5353`" since that's going to be MDNS normally.

Comment: That is so stupid.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**:  It doesn't exist see the following link; he offers a solution, similar to my first crack below: [Filtering mDNS in WS](https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/23518/mdns-protocol-filtering).  He proposes: `dns and udp.port eq 5353`

This being said, reference the wikipedia page:  [MDNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS)

You will see that it publishes to:

> IPv4 address 224.0.0.251 or IPv6 address FF02::FB
>   UDP Port 5353

I would recommend using `ip.dst==224.0.0.251` and, if that isn't enough, and that filter with one on the UDP port.

Answer (score 0):

mDNS packets are multicast (in opposite to unicast or broadcast) so you should filter them with one of the following filters:

`ip == multicast`

`ip == broadcast`

I know you already have the capture file but for future reference - you can filter only multicast traffic using capture filter `multicast`

Comment: Thanks for Answer, if i try ip == multicast it shows me nothing.. or what do you mean?

Comment: can you send me the pcap file so I could see what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

mdns and ip.addr = x.x.x.x
as filterstatement works for me (version 4.0.4)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).